# Carousel Fade Black Effect

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I would like to know how can I change the fade color instead of white, to black? I am using bootstrap 4.1

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.2.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/10.2.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="gradient">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="gradient">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="gradient">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-500kb.jpg" alt="First slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your problem is solved here : http://jsfiddle.net/HEzuM/4/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because this color is from opacity, not background-color of the img.